# Express + EJS prettify url ending

Tags: node.js, url, express, ejs

I have an express app that uses EJS view engine. Everything works fine, except the application adds weird characters to the end of the url of the views. For example,
one view looks like this:

```
localhost:3000/calendar#_=_
```

Now how could I get rid of those #*=* characters at the end of the url?

I set up my express like this:

```
var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/../views');
app.set('view_engine', 'ejs');
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/../public/favicon/favicon.ico'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Comment: That looks like something your client library (eg angularjs) is doing.  It's not native to express/ejs afaik

Comment: Front-end I currently only have jQuery + fullCalendar

Comment: Probably check the fullCalendar docs, then.

Comment: I found where this is related to: Facebook passport authentication